# Android FCM + Nearby conflict

Tags: android, firebase, google-nearby

I need both Firebase Cloud Messaging and Nearby support in my app.
**The latest allowed Nearby version is 9.0.0**. So, I have to use following dependencies:

```
//Firebase
compile ‘com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile ‘com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
//Nearby
compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby::9.0.0’
```

It compiles successfully but when I try to get Firebase instance app crashes with IllegalAccessError:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:114)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.obolus.poc.customer-1/base.apk)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Using of different versions for these components causes compile error. Firebase 10.0.1 without Nearby works fine but I need both.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

**Solution**

Perhaps it's a bug but for now to ensure that play-services plugin will check available versions correctly place line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**at the bottom** of your build.gradle file (below the dependencies block).

Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wrong the latest nearby is v10 the same as Firebase
use the following dependencies that are here under

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1
```

Comment: All Google play service components have the same version numbers.

Comment: You are right. I've just missed that now we need to put "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" line at the bottom of the gradle file. Thank you.